# Draw PDF for multi page in zendframwork

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, cgcontextdrawpdfpage

I am using function draw PDF in zendFreamwork but now i meet problem with many data many page but my `pdf` can draw only one page, for more data will lose. so have any solution can draw multi page ?

thanks in advance for helping.  I am looking to see your reply soon.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Zend_PDF about a form.
Is the same variables in all page?
If yes, try, if possible, to use a counter on yours variables, fields .. 
before:

```
$your_var = ...
...
```

after:

```
foreach ($pdf_pages as $cpt => $page){
  $var = 'your_var'.$cpt;
  $$var = ...
  ...
}
```

I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

PDF object has object pages as an array Zend_Pdf_Page class. You can add multiple pages you like.

```
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
$page1 = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
...
$pdf->pages[] = $page1;
$page2 = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
...
$pdf->pages[] = $page2;
$pdf->save('sample.pdf');
```